# Possible to get Excanvas to work in IE 8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, canvas, excanvas, beautytips

I used to work on a jQuery plugin named 'BeautyTips' and it was working just fine. But, since I've installed IE 8, this plugin stop working because it needs Excanvas to make IE draw the vectors, images etc.

I've tried to download the newer version of Excanvas but it's not working at all...

Comment: Still blows my mind that Microsoft brought out IE8 without native Canvas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try appending the canvas element to the document before initializing it using excanvas:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("targetElementID");
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute("width", 620);
canvas.setAttribute("height", 310);
canvas.setAttribute("class", "mapping");
foo.appendChild(canvas);
canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
```

Answer (score 16):

The new 'standards' mode of IE8 turns off some nonstandard features.  Among them VML, which is used by excanvas.  I just set for IE7 'standards' mode, so it still works.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Frustrating, but i don't know of any advantage brought up by IE8.

Comment: That's pretty good. When I had to use Canvas on IE8 I threw it into quirks mode instead, which sucked.

Comment: it used it at first, but kept getting on lots of problems on other parts of the page.  manually setting into IE7 compatibility fixed most, so i kept googling until found this item.  in theory future IE's (oh God, no!) will allow you to choose from a wide variety of 'standards', from past versions

Comment: mmm, the last version seems only to work only with the compatibility mode, for me too

Answer (score 14):

Yes, I have got excanvas working in IE8 standards mode (only tested for the usage we required). In the function **CanvasRenderingContext2D_** I commented out the line:

`//el.style.overflow = 'hidden';//fix IE8`

The width and height of the node object el was 0px by 0px, so not setting the overflow to hidden made the rendered item visible.

I did change the order of the creation of the **canvasPieTimer** a bit, to get the required result. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Looks like this may be where the issue is. Turning overflow off for the canvas element I was using fixed the issue when debugging.

Comment: +1 I would vote this up more!! Saved me a massive compatibility mode headache!!

Comment: No need to turn off standards mode - you are a legend!

Comment: This fix looks good, but if you try to use zoom, your graph will be visible over the canvas path.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have the most recent version of excanvas.js installed? (released in March 2009, hosted on the new Google Code project page)

I used the Beauty Tips Plugin in IE8 and AFAIK it worked in IE8 native mode.

Answer (score 1):

The latest bt plugin version fixes this issue for me.

Comment: @jeff, I've tried to use that version, but it didn't work it for me. I had to do some other stuff to make it works!

Comment: I'm using the lastest version but it doesn't work neither, I deleted my cache but still nothing. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Appending a canvas tag as a string of html with jquery doesn't work with the new version of excanvas. You have to use document.createElement('canvas') first.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still have this issue:
Beauty Tips version 0.9.5 fixes this issue. however if you have to use earlier version (like i do, as the new version introduced an issue of tips being closed prematurely in my page),
you should replace line 530 with these lines:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');  
$(canvas).attr('width', (numb($text.btOuterWidth(true)) + opts.strokeWidth*2)).attr('height', (numb($text.outerHeight(true)) + opts.strokeWidth*2)).appendTo($box).css({position: 'absolute', top: $text.btPosition().top, left: $text.btPosition().left, zIndex: opts.boxzIndex});
```

hope it helps.