# Excanvas.js doesn't work for me in IE8

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-8, excanvas

Trying to make a canvas effect work in IE8. With excanvas.js there is no problem in IE7, but in IE8, it doesn't work. The effect is named ECOTree, and I have made all the tricks and all the modifications included [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941170/does-anyone-could-make-excanvas-work-in-ie-8-with-jquery). Any suggestions to run this effect in IE8?

Here is the modified code for ie8 in ecotree.js:

```
// Make the <canvas> element.
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
jQuery(canvas).attr('width', 2000).attr('height', 7000).attr('id', 'ECOTreecanvas').appendTo(this.treeContainer);
if ((jQuery.browser.msie) && (parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10)<=8)){
    // For Internet Explorer, have excanvas initialize the canvas method
    // Modification, the major versions greater than 8 don't need excanvas.
    canvas.setAttribute('width', '2000');
    canvas.setAttribute('height', '7000');
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'ECOTreecanvas');
    this.treeContainer.append(canvas);
    if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
        canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show code. Excanvas works fine for me in IE8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to get Excanvas to work in IE 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941170/possible-to-get-excanvas-to-work-in-ie-8)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by forcing an event to update the canvas element. I know it is an unorthodox mechanism but apparently updating with jquery ready method was not enough

Answer (score -1):

Nothing you posted looks incorrect, you will need to provide more detail, however I can say that a lot of your code is redundant.

```
// Make the <canvas> element.
var canvas = $('<canvas id="ECOTreecanvas" width="2000" height="7000"></canvas>').appendTo($(this.treeContainer));
if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}
```

I am assuming here you only include excanvas when the browser is old.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there are a lot of redundant code, and your assumption is accepted I just include excanvas when the browser is old `<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqcanvas.js">//</script>
<![endif]-->`

Comment: Still not working, any suggestions, something i'm doing wrong or some new trick known?

Comment: @Pymoo If you have solved it yourself then share you solution as an answer and accept it. You never know if someone else might have the same problem. :)